# Python for loop on csv with multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I've got a series of csv and I want to read some unique values, then print each values for each csv.
To explain it better: I've got several csv with Type and Publisher columns. In each csv the Type and Publisher columns could have the same value repeated several times. If in Type column there is, i.e., "file" "file" "record" "file" "record", I want to print just "file" and "record".

I'm trying with:

```
publisher = [] #create lists for each value we want
type = []
for rec in attachment: #attachment is a list with the url of csv
    newFile = rec.replace("\\","/")
    print("I'm searching in "+newFile)
    download = requests.get(newFile) #get the file from url
    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8') #decode in utf-8

    csvFile = csv.DictReader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter='\t')  
    csvFile.fieldnames = [field.strip().lower() for field in csvFile.fieldnames]
        for row in csvFile:
          publisher.append(row["publisher"])
          type.append(row["type"])
    print(";".join(set(self.type)))
    print(";".join(set(self.publisher)))
```

This just prints ALL the values of the differents csv together, anytime it searchs into the next csv.

The output desired would be:

```
I'm searching in File 1
record; file
Publisher1
I'm searching in File 2
file
Publisher 2; Publisher 2A
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you expect? It's unclear to me what "some unique values" mean

Comment: I've edited the answer @CarlosMermingas, for that purpose I'm using set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to initialize your lists inside the loop:

```
for rec in attachment: #attachment is a list with the url of csv
    publisher = []                      # <-- HERE
    type = []                           # <-- HERE
    newFile = rec.replace("\\","/")
```

And instead of lists, you could use sets to begin with:

```
for rec in attachment: #attachment is a list with the url of csv
    publisher = set()
    type = set()
    newFile = rec.replace("\\","/")
```

If you use sets, you would use `add` instead of `append`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it works! I knew it was some stupid mistake like that that I was doing